# iOS: Is it possible to scan multiple QR Codes, detect them, and pick up one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, qr-code, avcapturesession, avcapture

I would like to know if there is a library, or a Github with the capability to detect several qrcodes and choose one of them.

For example if I scan that listing, I would see something that detect the surface (with the red square), and put them in red for example like this:

[image]

Then I could select the one I need by returning in the function the QRCode selected.

I use that type of scan for my app but it is not with QR Codes specifically: [WeScan](https://github.com/WeTransfer/WeScan) or [vue-qrcode-reader](https://github.com/gruhn/vue-qrcode-reader)
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The commercial software [Scandit](https://www.scandit.com/products/) supports features like this. I think the features is called *Matrix Scan*.

Comment: @ Codo Wow, I am going to check that, it seems very interesting :D